# count max levels of a tree below each node in r

Tags: r, tree, hierarchy

In R, I need to get the number of layers below each node in a tree. If my data are:

```
from,to
A,Z
B,Z
C,A
D,A
E,A
F,D
G,D
H,G
I,C
```

The results should be:

```
A 3
B 0
C 1
D 2
E 0
F 0
G 1
H 0
I 0
Z 4
```

I've been trying to figure something out with `data.tree` but I can't seem to figure it out, and not sure what other packages would be helpful here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the logic for going from input to output? I don't understand how you get "A 3, B 0" etc.

Comment: If you draw out the tree, it's the max number of levels below each node. B, E, F, H, I all have 0 other nodes pointing to them. For A, it has 3 children, and the path from A->D->G->H is the longest so it gets 3. The others would be A->E; A->C->I; and A->D->F.

Comment: It appears that when you say from A to Z you interpret that as A in one step below Z.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: It might be something along that line, but that only counts the number of nodes pointed to a specific node and not the number of levels below each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this using the `igraph` package.  You can convert your edgelist to a graph and then compute the distances between nodes. You just want the maximum 
distance.

```
## Your data
EdgeList = as.matrix(read.table(text="from to
A Z
B Z 
C A
D A
E A
F D
G D
H G
I C",
header=TRUE))

## convert to an igraph graph
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_edgelist(EdgeList)

## Make a function to compute the height of a node
height = function(v) {
    D = distances(g, to=v, mode="out")
    max(D[D != Inf])
}

## Apply it to all nodes
sapply(V(g), height)
A Z B C D E F G H I 
3 4 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0
```

If you really want these in alphabetical order, you can order them with

```
H = sapply(V(g), height)
H[order(names(H))]
```

Answer (score 3):

With data.tree:

```
EdgeList <- read.table(text="from to
A Z
B Z 
C A
D A
E A
F D
G D
H G
I C",
header=TRUE)

library(data.tree)
dt <- FromDataFrameNetwork(EdgeList)
```

Either in tree format:

```
print(dt, lvls = function(node) node$height - 1)
```

This will print like this:

```
   levelName            lvls
1  Z                    4
2   ¦--A                3
3   ¦   ¦--C            1
4   ¦   ¦   °--I        0
5   ¦   ¦--D            2
6   ¦   ¦   ¦--F        0
7   ¦   ¦   °--G        1
8   ¦   ¦       °--H    0
9   ¦   °--E            0
10  °--B                0
```

Or in the format you requested

```
dt$Get("height") - 1
```

If you need it sorted in the original order, you can add a sorting variable to EdgeList.

Comment: I like your answer, Could you you give me solution for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039222/how-to-implement-hierarchical-multilevel-datatable-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment91031196_52039222