# Network/tree data: calculate number of independent trees and average maximum edges per independent tree

Tags: r, tree, ggraph, tidygraph

I would like to draw network plots using `tidygraph` and `ggraph`.

I have a larger tibble with items connected via `from` and `to`.
Some of the trees are connected (`a0` and `b0` in the example).

I would like to:

1. Count the number of independent trees
2. Calculate the average maximum edges=connections per independent tree. The average maximum edges should be calculated "downstreams", i.e. from `a0` to `k2` or `a4` not `a0` to `b0` in the example data.

Example:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)


# make edges
edges<- tibble(from = c("a0","a1","a2","a3","b0","b1","c0","c1","a2","k1"),
               to = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","b1","a3","c1","c2","k1","k2"))


# makenodes
nodes  <- unique(c(edges$from,edges$to))
tibble(node=nodes,
       label=nodes) -> nodes


# make correct dataframe                 
routes_igraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges,
                                       vertices = nodes,
                                       directed = TRUE)

routes_tidy <- as_tbl_graph(routes_igraph)

#plot network
ggraph(routes_tidy, layout = "tree") + 
  geom_edge_link() + 
  geom_node_point() + 
  theme_graph() +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = label), repel = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Desired output**

1. Number of independent trees of the given `edges` and `nodes`: `2`
2. Average maximum edges per independen trees: `3.5, 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. It borrows a function `height` from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134083/8245406), modified to count `"in"` vertices.

```r
height <- function(v, g) {
  D <- distances(g, to=v, mode="in")
  max(D[D != Inf])
}

cmp <- components(routes_igraph)
sp <- split(names(cmp$membership), cmp$membership)
sub_tree_list <- lapply(sp, \(v) induced.subgraph(routes_igraph, v))
sub_tree_height <- Map(\(g, v) sapply(v, height, g = g), sub_tree_list, sp)

# number of components
length(sp)
#> [1] 2

# height of each sub-tree
sapply(sub_tree_height, max)
#> 1 2 
#> 4 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To get the maxima per initial node and their averages per sub-tree, this works.

```r
initials_list <- lapply(sp, \(x) x[grep("0", x)])
sub_tree_max_height <- Map(\(g, v) sapply(v, height, g = g), sub_tree_list, initials_list)
sapply(sub_tree_max_height, mean)
#>   1   2 
#> 3.5 2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. What would be 2) average maximum edges per independent tree (i.e. the average maximum edges of all subtrees that form that tree)? In my example it would be 3.5 and 2.

Comment: Something like this works for me:

`nodes %>% filter(str_detect(label,"0")) %>% pull(label) -> initials`
                 

`get_average <- function(x){ x %>%  filter(ind%in%initials) %>% summarise(mean=mean(values))}`

`sub_tree_height %>%  map(~stack(.)) %>%  map(as_tibble) %>%  map(get_average)`